# can java.util.BitSet hold more than MAX_INT no. of bits?

Tags: java, bitset

As the `BitSet.get()` function uses an `int` as an argument, I was thinking whether I could store more than 2^32 bits in a `BitSet`, and if so how would I retrieve them?

I am doing a Project Euler problem where I need to generate primes till 10^10. The algorithm I'm currently using to generate primes is the Erathonesus' Sieve, storing the boolean values as bits in a BitSet. Any workaround for this?

Comment: Try to use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) with 'BigInteger.nextProbablePrime`. For me it works in the way I expect.

Comment: The sieve of Eratosthenes is not intended for finding large primes.  I would recommend a different approach.  Wikipedia's entry recommends the pseudosquares prime sieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a list of bitsets as `List<BitSet>` and when the end of one bitset has been reached you could move to the next one.

However, I think your approach is probably incorrect. Even if you use a single bit for each number you need `10^10` bits which is about `1 GB` memory (8 bits in a byte and 1024^3 bytes in a GB). Most Project Euler problems should be solvable without needing that much memory.

Comment: I'm doing the 'Primes With Runs' problem, no. 111. I probably need a better prime generator. Thanks Anyway.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's limited by the int indexing in its interface.
So they didn't bother exploiting all its potential, (about 64x downsized) probably because it wasn't feasible to use that much RAM.
I worked on a `LongBitSet` implementation, [published it here](https://github.com/juanmf/LongBitSet).

It can take:

```
//2,147,483,647 For reference, this is Integer.MAX_VALUE
137,438,953,216 LongBitSet max size (bits)
0b1111111_11111111_11111111_11111100_000000L in binary
```

Had to address corner cases, in the commit history you can see the 1st commit being a copy paste from `java.util.BitSet`.

See factory method:

```
    public static LongBitSet getMaxSizeInstance() {
        // Integer.MAX_VALUE - 3 << ADDRESS_BITS_PER_WORD
        return new LongBitSet( 0b1111111_11111111_11111111_11111100_000000L);
    }
```

Note: `-Xmx24G -Xms24G -ea`  Min GB needed to start JVM with to call `getMaxSizeInstance()` without `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Comment: I used it to compute primes, and it shows very good performance for large sets. implemented this sieve that copies fwd current set n times in same list [The dynamic of prime numbers](https://mirror.xyz/0x62514E8C74B1B188dFCD76D2171c96EF1845Ba02/PhwGsMoDsGGfbagtxAhjM5OyvIPnFfF6dhBYb4QICfQ)