# Is BitSet worth using?

Tags: java, memory-management, bitset

I made a Java object that has a lot of Boolean fields. I was considering using [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) when I started questioning its usefulness.

Of course, one would use it for memory reasons, since a `boolean` is 8 bits alone, 4 in an array. With `BitSet`, each value is stored as a single bit. **However, wouldn't the memory saved be blown out of the water by the following overhead?**

- `BitSet` class and method definitions meta data (per runtime)
- The objects needed as keys to semantically retrieve the values (per class using `BitSet`)
- The meta data for the `bits` array in `BitSet` (per instance)

versus using `boolean`s:

- boolean value (per instance)

---

Let's take a look at the following class:

```java
private boolean isVisible; // 8 bits per boolean * 82 booleans = ~0.6Kb
// 81 lines later...
private boolean isTasty;

// ...

public boolean isVisible() { return isVisible; }
// ...
public boolean isTasty() { return isTasty; }

public void setVisible(boolean newVisibility) { isVisible = newVisibility; }
// ...
public void setTasty(boolean newTastiness) { isTasty = newTastiness; }
```

Now, if I were to combine all my `boolean`s into one `BitSet` and still keep my code semantic, I might do this:

```java
private static final int _K_IS_VISIBLE = 1; // 32 bits per key * 82 keys = ~2.5Kb
// ...
private static final int _K_IS_TASTY = 82;
private BitSet bools = new BitSet(82); // 2 longs = 64b

// ...

public boolean isVisible() { return bools.get(_K_IS_VISIBLE); }
// ...
public boolean isTasty() { return bools.get(_K_IS_TASTY); }

public void setVisible(boolean newVisibility) { bools.set(_K_IS_VISIBLE, newVisibility); }
// ...
public void setTasty(boolean newTastiness) { bools.set(_K_IS_TASTY, newTastiness); }
```

---

### tl;dr

```java
costOfUsingBitSet =
    bitSetMethodsAndClassMetaData + // BitSet class overhead
    (numberOfKeysToRetrieveBits * Integer.SIZE) + // Semantics overhead
    (numberOfBitSetsUsed * floor((bitsPerBitSet / Long.SIZE) + 1)); // BitSet internal array overhead
```

and possibly more. Whereas using `boolean`s would be:

```java
costOfBooleans = 
    (numberOfBooleansOutsideArrays * 8) + 
    (numberOfBooleansInsideArrays * 4);
```

**I feel like the overhead of `BitSet` is much higher. Am I right?**

Comment: That *overhead* of the memory you point out doesn't live in the heap unless the methods use internal variables, if that's your concern. Also, we're not talking of MegaBytes of memory being consumed, but bits. Unless you work building a critical-memory system like software for a pacemaker, this concern is worthless.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I'm just concerned about overall system memory. This is for Android, so I must think about devices with 512MB. Our app is already absolutely enormous, so any way to slim that down will help a lot if we use that method across the whole thing. Either way, my question stands: **what's the benefit of `BitSet`?**

Comment: 512MB of RAM  used to be **enormous** when `BitSet` was introduced. Don't worry about the overhead.

Comment: Well, after reading the source code of `BitSet` for Java 1.6, the only fields that will affect memory are `private long[] words`, `private transient int wordsInUse = 0;` and `private transient boolean sizeIsSticky = false;`. Everything else you're putting into discussion should be already loaded by JVM for you, so there's no problem.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the objects needed as keys to semantically retrieve the values (per class using BitSet)'? There are no such objects. There are an integer to index the array, and a bit mask and shift count to extract the bit. These are local variables, or possibly just locally computed values on the stack, and they are not objects.

Comment: I wouldn't use `BitSet` to replace a constant number of `boolean`s, only when I could have arbitrarily many of them -- e.g. if I was replacing an arbitrary `Set<Integer>`.

Comment: @EJP I mean like my example's `_K_IS_VISIBLE`. I suppose "object" wasn't the best terminology, but still. It's easier to tell what `bools.get(_K_IS_TASTY);` means, and nigh impossible to tell what `bools.get(82);` means.

Comment: I do not understand. You can have names for your keys in either case. You're also overlooking that both the space-efficiency and the capacity of a BitSet are much greater than those of an array of boolean. You're comparing apples and oranges, and you're also jumping to conclusions.

Comment: *Our app is already absolutely enormous, so any way to slim that down will help a lot* since we know **nothing** of your application this is going into a debate and that's not the point of this site. I will recommend doing the changes and check the results by using a profiler. Only then, for your specific case that we only know if you should replace a `boolean[]` by a `BitSet`, you will see if it was the right decision or not. Voting to close this question.

Comment: just have two `long` fields, and do bit masking yourself - not big deal.

Comment: @bayou.io That's what I've traditionally done, but I'm moving to a phase of coding where I'm attempting to utilize the creations of those who came before me, in hopes that they knew what they were doing better than I.

Comment: not in this case; the API doesn't really do much extra.

Comment: All of this makes hardly any sense to me. The integers you use for the keys will be shared amongst multiple 82-sized instances of `BitSet`. It's a constant that is added to the total amount and is completely, utterly irrelevant and negligible if compared to the massive win of dividing the real beef by 8. And if there's only one BitSet instance of 82 elements in the whole application, than the memory footprint is irrelevant in any case. What am I missing?

Comment: @gd1 - I assume he has thousands of object, each carrying its own 82 flags.

Comment: @bayou.io you're right about the situation, but wrong about the footprint; `static` fields only exist once per class, not per instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice space comparison here between `boolean[]` and `BitSet`:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-boolean-array-bitset-performance

[image: chart]
Think they swapped labels here. Should be more bits per memory (Blue) in `BitSet`.

##### The key takeaway here is, the BitSet beats the boolean[] in terms of the memory footprint, except for a minimal number of bits.

An alternative in your example is to use 2 `long` as bit flags.

```java
class A {
// 1st set
private static final long IS_VISIBLE_MASK = 1; 
...
private static final long IS_DARK_MASK = 1 << 63 ; 

// 2nd set...
private static final long IS_TASTY_MASK = 1;
...

// IS_VISIBLE_MASK .. IS_DARK_MASK
long data1;

// IS_TASTY_MASK ...
long data2;

boolean isDark = (data1 & IS_DARK_MASK) != 0; 

}
```

### Limitations

BitSet comes with silly limitations, as you can reach a max of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` bits. I needed as much bits as I could store in RAM. [So modified the original implementation](https://github.com/juanmf/LongBitSet) in two ways:

- It waste less computing for fixed sized LongBitSets (i.e. user specifies length at construction time).
- it can reach the last bit in the biggest possible word array.

Added details on limitations in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475794/can-java-util-bitset-hold-more-than-max-int-no-of-bits/70416032#70416032)

Answer (score 4):

`BitSet` will be less memory, using only one bit is far more efficient. The method overhead you are looking at is once no matter how many instances of your class you have, so its cost is amortized basically to 0

The advantage of a `boolean` over an array of `boolean`s or a `BitSet` is that it is not an `Object`, so you have one less level of indirection

Cache hits are a primary driver for performance so you have to weigh fewer cache hits with the higher likelihood of evicting data from the cache due to higher memory consumption

Roughly speaking a few `boolean`s will be faster but more memory, as you have more fields or get closer to huge numbers, the scale will top towards `BitSet`

Comment: Performance isn't one of my concerns; if it were, I'd've asked about the amount of computation needed to just perform `bools.set(1, false);`

Comment: BitSet will be less memory, using only one bit is far more efficient

Comment: Of course, I knew that going in; that's why I'm considering it. My reason for asking this was because I was concerned about what happens around that 1 bit (the unused bits in the `long`s, the meta data for the array the `long`s are stored in, the meta data for the `BitSet` class and its arrays, the `int`s needed as keys to retrieve the bits, etc.)

Comment: @Supuhstar if you see the source code, you will see that *that overhead* is worthless of concern. But then again, you won't be sure unless you prove yourself using one or the other is best suited for your case by the usage of a profiler.

Comment: @Suphustar 'The unused bits in the longs' take up 7 bytes in your example, out of *one* long, or 8 bytes total. Your array of 82 booleans takes up 82 bytes. 'The `ints` needed as keys' are local variables, not instance variables, and I cannot understand why you would think otherwise.

Comment: Shouldn't be BitSet better for cache? I mean, data loaded in the cache in case of BitSet is array of long, so on repeated checks on single long will have 63 hits? Whereas 64*4B will be less likely cached in the single block.

Comment: a `Bitset(1)` is much worse that a `boolean`.  `BitSet(1000)` is far better than 1000 `boolean`s - testing will show the inflextion point on your system